# Purpose of if(0){ //code }?

Tags: javascript

Quick question. I just came across the following in a JS file:

```
if (0) {
    // code
}
```

What's the purpose of this if statement? Which cases would the code execute? It currently doesn't run the code in the if clause.

Comment: Quick way to comment or disable debugging code possibly?

Comment: Just in case someone does a `#define 0 1`?

Comment: @Marc B: You do know that's impossible in JavaScript don't you? :)

Comment: thanks for all the answers. I've never thought of that way of commenting out code. Sorry I can't mark all answers below as the answer =/

Comment: @pimvdb Is there any language where you _can_ #define a numeric token?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like an artifact of the development process.  Wrapping code like that gives you a quick, 1-character way to effectively comment out a block of code.  It's quicker to toggle than a typical multi-line comment.

Answer (score 6):

Someone has used that to effectively comment out a large chunk of code.

They probably meant to remove it entirely before releasing to the public, but forgot.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, in Javascript, some code runs even in such block. For example, variables being defined in `if(0)` block will be defined with the value `undefined`:

```
if (0)
{
    var f = 1;
}
f; //undefined
g; //ReferenceError
```

Another good example is the case of declaring functions in blocks. This is undefined behaviour in Ecmascript, so the results may vary across browsers:

```
if (0)
{
    function f() {}
}
typeof f; //"undefined" in Firefox, "function" in other browsers
```

IIRC some bulletin board software generates `0` or `1` on the server side; see @eds's post.

Comment: In Chrome (WebKit) the `typeof` does return `function`.

Comment: I'll explain. First one is because of hoisting feature of javascript: declarations will be moved to the top of the nearest scope ('if' is not a scope). So the code really is: var f; if (0) { f = 1 } f; g;

Comment: @pimvdb I've edited my post. I don't have currently all major browsers installed so I couldn't test the behaviour, but I remembered that some older version of Safari was returning "undefined".

Answer (score 2):

It won't run. It could be someone was trying to comment out the code and there were too many `/* */` in the middle (or maybe there was some other reason why the original author didn't want to use `/* */`?). Regardless of the reason, `if(0){}` means `if(false){}`. The code between the braces will never run.

Answer (score 1):

that's possible temporary **disabled** part of code

Answer (score 1):

It's probably just an easy way to toggle enabling/disabling code, but what you may be seeing is JavaScript code that was rendered by a server-side language.  So, for example, if you were writing in PHP, and you wanted client-side JavaScript to run if your PHP variable $doThis was non-null, you might write

```
 if (<? echo $doThis; ?>) {
  // do stuff...
 }
```

There aren't many situations where this happens, but I know Blogger uses technique where it displays the number of comments below a post.

Comment: `null`, and indeed `false`, stringify in PHP as the empty string.  So you would get `if() { ... }`, which is syntactically invalid.  $doThis would have to be a numeric 0 or a string representation of something to that effect.

Comment: Is there any real reason to do this, rather than use PHP to conditionally write out the whole block of code?

Comment: @Stewart there's no need to, but that way you can just echo a number instead of having a whole if statement